# Swift can't change imageview frame inside xib uiview

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimageview, swift3

I'm using Swift 3 and trying to change my UIImageView width and height that inside xib

This is my code:

```
let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Custom", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as! UIView           
view.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(i) * self.sView.frame.size.width, y: self.sView.frame.origin.y, width: self.sView.frame.size.width, height: self.sView.frame.size.height)    

let imageView = view.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
```

when I try to change the imageview frame like this

```
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: imageView.frame.origin.x, y: imageView.frame.origin.y - 40, width: 200, height: imageView.frame.height)
```

nothing change when I try to run it, please help me how to fix this problem

Comment: have you got proper imageview  in this line : let imageView = view.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView

Comment: var frame = self. imageView.frame
        frame.size.width = 100;
        frame.size.height = 100;
        self. imageView.frame = frame
        self. imageView .setNeedsDisplay()

Comment: @KKRocks I already set it properly, I can change the image of the imageview without any problem, just can't change the width and height

Comment: @karthikeyan the code not working, already try it several times

Comment: First thing. Do you display the imageView properly at first?
Second, try using the bounds of the imageView instead of it's frame as they don't use the same coordinate space. imageView.frame = CGRect(x: imageView.bounds.origin.x, y: imageView.bounds.origin.y - 40, width: 200, height: imageView.bounds.height)

Comment: and finish with a layoutIfNeeded()

Comment: @Ocunidee same result, not working.. my Imageview still same with the one I set in the xib, my Imageview already set properly and I can change the image in code without any problem

Comment: you are using auto layout? I think you problem is there

Comment: @Ocunidee I try to use `view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` but all my layout now look mess and thats not the problem I try to use `imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: 200, height: 50)` to see if my imageview are moving but there nothing happen, all still the same and with my whole layout mess

Comment: Where is your code? Hopefully not in viewDidLoad....

Comment: why don't you have the constraints of your imageView as IBOutlets and modify them instead of the frame of the imageView. If you want to change programmatically the frame, you should add the imageView programmatically in its parent view

Comment: @dfd nope, I call the code after I retrieve the image using alamofire and not in viewDidLoad

Comment: @Ocunidee how to call constraints as IBOutlets from xib to the controller ?

Comment: just like you do for buttons, when you select your image view in the XIB you should see the constraints as blue lines. You can just select each of them in turn and right click drag to your view class (you will need to subclass UIView) and give a specific class to your UIView in XIB. It's then easy to modify from within your controller like this yourView.leftConstraint.constant = 20

Answer (score 1):

I end up set identifier for my constraint in my xib
and call it from my controller like this

```
for subview in view.subviews {
            for constraint in subview.constraints as [NSLayoutConstraint] {
                if constraint.identifier == "imageWidth" {
                    constraint.constant = view.frame.width * 0.5
                }
            }
        }
```

and I can control the width, the height, the x and y from my controller

Comment: Very clever! But it would be better to configure an _outlet_ to the width constraint. Then you would have a _direct_ reference to it, and you could just change its `constant` instantly at any time.